# Parse XML Headers

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse out the following:

```
'Execute Query'
'Execute Query'
'Execute Query'
'2018-11-28 00:00'
'2018-11-28 23:59'
```

My XML looks like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?><Report Type='SLA Report'
 SiteName='Execute Query'
 SLA_Name='Execute Query'
 SLA_Description='Execute Query'
 From='2018-11-28 00:00'
 Thru='2018-11-28 23:59' 
 obj_device='4500'
 locations='69,31,'
>
  <Objective Type='Availability'/>
  <Goal>99.93</Goal>
  <Actual>100.00</Actual>
  <Compliant>Yes</Compliant>
  <Errors>0</Errors>
</Report>
```

Here's the code that I'm testing.

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)

for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)


for sla in root.findall('Type'):
    goal = sla.find('Goal').text
    actual = sla.find('Actual').text
    compliant = sla.find('Compliant').text
    errors = sla.find('Errors').text
    checks = sla.find('Checks').text
    data=[goal,actual,compliant,errors,checks]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    print(df)
```

I got the 'root' items fine (Goal, Actual, etc.), but I can't seem to get the items at the top.  How can I get those first 5 items and load them into a data frame?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "items" on the top are called attributes of a tag.

You can read them in the following manner:

```
root.attrib["SiteName"]
```

or

```
root.get("SiteName")
```

[etree examples on docs.python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements)

Comment: Perfect.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  It's difficult to solve a problem when you don't even know the naming conventions of the problem you're trying to solve.  Thanks so much!!